# Compare two Objects and determine the parent node of differed properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario, were need to compare treeObject1 and treeObject2 to determine the exact difference at property level and find the parent of modified node.

In below provided objects, I need to get output as color blue. Since the difference is at otherObj2.

```
treeObject1  = {
color: "red", 
value: 10, 
otherObj: { 
   color: "blue", 
   otherObj2: { 
     otherColor: "blue", 
     otherValue: 20,
    }
}
}

treeObject2  = {
color: "red", 
value: 10, 
otherObj: { 
   color: "blue", 
   otherObj2: { 
     otherColor: "Green", 
     otherValue: 20,
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you need just the different value or the property/ies as well? what should happen if more than one property is different? what have you tried? maybe you have a look here, too: [mcve]

Comment: I need to find the difference of the value at property level on complete tree hierarchy and find the parent node of that property which was modified or had difference

Comment: do you like to get `otherColor`?

Comment: Yes, I want otherColor and its parent color i.e. blue. Consider, If we have multiple childrens inside "otherObj2", like "otherObj21". If the difference is available in otherColor at both levels. Then my parents should display the "otherObj.color" for first level scenario and "otherObj2.color" for 2nd level scenario

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: I'm not able to determine exact approach to write this code, it would be helpful, if we have some library which does this operation or an javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the key "otherObj" as well let me know, that can easily be added. Otherwise here is a working version of what you were looking for.

This uses a combination of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
treeObject1 = {
  color: "red",
  value: 10,
  otherObj: {
    color: "blue",
    otherObj2: {
      otherColor: "blue",
      otherValue: 20,
    }
  }
}

treeObject2 = {
  color: "red",
  value: 10,
  otherObj: {
    color: "blue",
    otherObj2: {
      otherColor: "Green",
      otherValue: 20,
    }
  }
}

const findParentNode = (obj1, obj2, parent = null) => {
   
   if(parent === null) parent = obj2;

   //since the structures are the same we only get keys from the first object
   const keys = Object.keys(obj1);
   
   let result = null;
   //iterate through every key
   keys.every(key=>{
     //if it's an object... then we recall findParentNode (recursive)
     if(obj1[key] instanceof Object){
        result = findParentNode(obj1[key], obj2[key], obj2);
        //If result from findParentNode is not null then a difference was found. 
        //Return false to stop the every method.
        if(result !== null) return false;
        
     }else if(obj1[key] !== obj2[key]){
        //If the objects are different we found a difference
        //Set the parent as the difference
        result = parent;
        return false;
     }
     //return true to keep on looping
     return true;
  });
  //return the result
  return result;
}

console.log(findParentNode(treeObject1, treeObject2));
```

** note that the above snippet will return "null" if nothing was found. **

Answer (score 1):

You could use a nested approach for objects and by checking the values.

```js
function getDiffParents(object1, object2, parent = {}) {
    return Object.assign(...Object.entries(object1).map(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
        ? getDiffParents(v, object2[k], object1)
        : v === object2[k]
            ? {}
            : parent
    ));
}

var treeObject1 = { color: "red", value: 10, otherObj: { color: "blue", otherObj2: { otherColor: "blue", otherValue: 20 } } },
    treeObject2 = { color: "red", value: 10, otherObj: { color: "blue", otherObj2: { otherColor: "Green", otherValue: 20 } } };

console.log(getDiffParents(treeObject1, treeObject2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```